# how to create a custom VagrantError class that does not use i18n?

Tags: vagrant

I would like to create a custom `VagrantError` class that does not use i18n for the error message.

The [Vagrant API docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mitchellh/vagrant/Vagrant/Errors) show how to create a customer error message

```rb
class MyError < Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError
  error_key "my_error"
end
```

The docs also state:

> If you don't want to use I18n, you can override the #initialize method
>   and set your own error message.

I've tried the following:

```rb
class MissingPluginError < Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError
  def initialize
    error_message =  "Vagrant Triggers plugin is required. Install using:"
    error_message += "'vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers'"
  end 
end
```

However, the only output produced when I `raise MissingPluginError.new` is:

```
MissingPluginError
```

**Question**: how can I create a custom `VagrantError` class that does not use i18n for the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do it.  I also decided to parameterise the error message so that the plugin name is passed in:

```rb
class MissingPluginError < Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError
  def initialize(plugin)
    error_message =  "#{plugin} plugin is required. Install using:\n"
    error_message += "'vagrant plugin install #{plugin}'"
    StandardError.instance_method(:initialize).bind(self).call(error_message)
  end 
end
```

And the error is raised like so:

```rb
unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-triggers")
  raise MissingPluginError.new 'vagrant-triggers'
end
```

Here is some [source code](https://github.com/mocoso/vagrant-bundler/blob/efced2dc5328665c7164757b117c3f28f653cbc9/lib/vagrant_bundler/errors.rb) that I found that shown me how to solve the problem.